# what does linux command "ps auwwx" mean?

Tags: linux, process, terminal, command

What does "auwwx" mean in the command "ps auwwx"?

---

According to the "man ps"

ps - report process status

ps gives a snapshot of the current processes. If you want a repetitive update of this status, use top. This man page documents the /proc-based version of ps, or tries to.

Comment: This question is off-topic here as it's not a programming question. Try the [Unix&Linux StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) website instead.

Comment: Why is this question off-topic? Currently, there are 68598 questions with linux tag, but we cannot ask unix/linux questions in stackoverflow?

Comment: Because it's not about programming, it's about a Unix command. There's a stack exchange website dedicated to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -w option sets the output to wide, and -ww (w twice) make it unlimited. aux (select all processes,select by effective user id,Lift the BSD-style "must have a tty" restriction x)