# What does www mean in ps auxwww?

Tags: process, terminal, ps

I found that ps aux lists processes that are currently running and I found other people mentioning `ps auxwww` . I am wondering what this means? or what it does? What's the difference between `ps aux` and `ps auxwww` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does linux command "ps auwwx" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151339/what-does-linux-command-ps-auwwx-mean)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To quote the `man` page (on Mac OS, other systems will vary slightly, but the idea is the same):

> **-w**
>   Use 132 columns to display information, instead of the default which is your window size.  **If the -w option is specified more than once**, ps will use as many columns as
>                necessary without regard for your window size.  When output is not to a terminal, an unlimited number of columns are always used.

Comment: so basically, if you forget how to display full width, you can also just use `ps aux | cat`. Very good to remember.

Answer (score 3):

ps auxwww is useful when you have a lot of data (how many columns you want)